# rank over union with joined tables sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, rank

I need to make a complex SQL query and add row numbers to it.
My query has 3 tables joined, added a custom row with union.
No matter how I try, I get syntax errors, please help me finding the solution.

Main query:

```
select null as EAN, 
       null as CustomsCode,
       ProductId as SupplierItemCode,
      '![CDATA['+Product.Name+']' as ItemDescription,
      '![CDATA['+Product.ShortDescription+']' as ItemNote, 
       null as VATType, 
      'CU' as PackageType, 
       Quantity as OrderQuantity,
      'darab' as UnitOfMeasure,
       UnitPriceExclTax as OrderedUnitNetPrice 
from [Order] inner join OrderItem on [Order].Id=OrderItem.OrderId 
     Inner join Product on OrderItem.ProductId=Product.Id 
where OrderId='150960'
UNION 
select null as EAN,
       null as CustomsCode,
       '00001' as SupplierItemCode, 
       '![CDATA[Szállítási díj]' as ItemDescription,
       '![CDATA[A termék postázási költsége]' as ItemNote,
       null as VATType, 'CU' as PackageType, 
       '1' as OrderQuantity, 
       'darab' as UnitOfMeasure, 
       OrderShippingExclTax as OrderedUnitNetPrice 
from [Order] 
Where [Order].Id='150960'
```

I need to add rank() to this table without getting same numbers as row number
My version was:

```
select Row_Number() OVER (Order by ProductID) as LineNumber,
       null as EAN,
       null as CustomsCode,
       ProductId as SupplierItemCode,
       '![CDATA['+Product.Name+']' as ItemDescription,
       '![CDATA['+Product.ShortDescription+']' as ItemNote,
        null as VATType,
       'CU' as PackageType, 
       Quantity as OrderQuantity,
       'darab' as UnitOfMeasure,
        UnitPriceExclTax as OrderedUnitNetPrice 
from [Order] inner join OrderItem on [Order].Id=OrderItem.OrderId
     Inner join Product on OrderItem.ProductId=Product.Id 
where OrderId='150960' 
UNION 
select Row_Number() OVER (Order by Id) as LineNumber,
      null as EAN, null as CustomsCode,
     '00001' as SupplierItemCode,
     '![CDATA[Szállítási díj]' as ItemDescription,
     '![CDATA[A termék postázási költsége]' as ItemNote, 
     null as VATType, 'CU' as PackageType, '1' as OrderQuantity, 
    'darab' as UnitOfMeasure, 
     OrderShippingExclTax as OrderedUnitNetPrice 
 from [Order] 
 Where [Order].Id='150960'
```

Which resulted row numbers: 1,1,2, I got same result with Rank()

Can anyone help?

The way I tried:

```
    Select Rank() OVER (ORDER BY ProductId) as LineNumber, 
   From (select Row_Number() OVER (Order by ProductID) as LineNumber,
       null as EAN,
       null as CustomsCode,
       ProductId as SupplierItemCode,
       '![CDATA['+Product.Name+']' as ItemDescription,
       '![CDATA['+Product.ShortDescription+']' as ItemNote,
        null as VATType,
       'CU' as PackageType, 
       Quantity as OrderQuantity,
       'darab' as UnitOfMeasure,
        UnitPriceExclTax as OrderedUnitNetPrice 
from [Order] inner join OrderItem on [Order].Id=OrderItem.OrderId
     Inner join Product on OrderItem.ProductId=Product.Id 
where OrderId='150960' 
UNION 
select Row_Number() OVER (Order by Id) as LineNumber,
      null as EAN, null as CustomsCode,
     '00001' as SupplierItemCode,
     '![CDATA[Szállítási díj]' as ItemDescription,
     '![CDATA[A termék postázási költsége]' as ItemNote, 
     null as VATType, 'CU' as PackageType, '1' as OrderQuantity, 
    'darab' as UnitOfMeasure, 
     OrderShippingExclTax as OrderedUnitNetPrice 
 from [Order] 
 Where [Order].Id='150960')
```

Comment: I think this because you have used the same condition in both queries, but the second one results two rows with two ranks 1, 2 and the first query results only one row with rank 1. But, what is the expected results you are looking for?

Comment: What is the syntax error you getting?

Comment: You have your row_number() in multiple queries, why would you think you wouldn't get duplicate values?  Union everything together, then select from that with your row_number().

Comment: I added the version that I can't get to work

Comment: And what is the problem in your query? Can you please explain what is the expected results and what is the problems in your queries?

Comment: Well this version says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From'."

the expected result  is having a table with the results of the union-ed queries, with a first column, that contains row numbers from 1 to x depending on the number of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question then I think you need to put your `ROW_NUMBER` expression outside the union as follows:

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY T.SupplierItemCode) AS LineNumber,
  T.EAN,
  T.CustomsCode,
  T.SupplierItemCode,
  T.ItemDescription,
  T.ItemNote,
  T.VATType,
  T.PackageType,
  T.OrderQuantity,
  T.UnitOfMeasure,
  T.OrderedUnitNetPrice
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      NULL AS EAN,
      NULL AS CustomsCode,
      ProductId AS SupplierItemCode,
      '![CDATA[' + Product.Name + ']' AS ItemDescription,
      '![CDATA[' + Product.ShortDescription + ']' AS ItemNote,
      NULL AS VATType,
      'CU' AS PackageType,
      Quantity AS OrderQuantity,
      'darab' AS UnitOfMeasure,
      UnitPriceExclTax AS OrderedUnitNetPrice
    FROM
      [Order]
      INNER JOIN OrderItem
        ON [Order].Id = OrderItem.OrderId
      INNER JOIN Product
        ON OrderItem.ProductId = Product.Id
    WHERE
      OrderId = '150960'
    UNION
    SELECT
      NULL AS EAN,
      NULL AS CustomsCode,
      '00001' AS SupplierItemCode,
      '![CDATA[Szállítási díj]' AS ItemDescription,
      '![CDATA[A termék postázási költsége]' AS ItemNote,
      NULL AS VATType,
      'CU' AS PackageType,
      '1' AS OrderQuantity,
      'darab' AS UnitOfMeasure,
      OrderShippingExclTax AS OrderedUnitNetPrice
    FROM
      [Order]
    WHERE
      [Order].Id = '150960'
  ) T
```

Answer (score 3):

You will get duplicate values in RANK, DENSE_RANK and ROW_NUMBER if the value you are ranking is not unique in the record order.

Your are applying a rank to both queries in your union and each will return an independent rank order containing 1. I think you want to return a unique value in both of the union statements and then rank the result with a sub query.

You could avoid this by setting the unique value to

```
SELECT
    Count=Row_Number() OVER (Order by UniqueValue) as LineNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT
        UniqeValue=NEWID()
    FROM
      X

    UNION

    SELECT
        UniqeValue=NEWID()
    FROM
      X
)AS X
```

Comment: Yes that sounds closer to my desired results but could you help me, with filling this example with my real code? Sorry I know it might take some time, but I don't quite get how it would look exactly